# How to use Bootstrap Multiselect in Rails views?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, multi-select

I am trying to implement bootstrap multiselect field in my rails app.

Making use of the bootstrap-multiselect_rails gem found here (https://github.com/TrevorS/bootstrap-multiselect_rails)

Have it installed and configured successfully but in my form am not able to select multiple vales. It allows me to select only an single value.

Right now my code looks like this:

```
<%= f.collection_select :role_pm, User.where(:user_role => 'Project Manager'), :name, :name, {}, {:multiple => 'true'}, {class: "role_pm"} %>
```

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: can you provide generated html code for `select` tag?

Comment: <td>
      <label for="project_role_pm">Project Manager</label><br>
      <h style="color:black"><select class="role_pm" name="project[role_pm]" id="project_role_pm"><option value="Joana Steuber DDS">Joana Steuber DDS</option>
<option value="Tobin Parisian">Tobin Parisian</option>
<option value="Rohitraj Sachan">Rohitraj Sachan</option>
<option value="Sim Denesik">Sim Denesik</option>
<option value="Mario Shanahan Jr.">Mario Shanahan Jr.</option></select></h>
    </td>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally got this working. I have Update the line of code in this answer which has caused me a lot of agony over the past 2 days or so

```
<%= f.collection_select :role_pm, User.where(:user_role => 'Project Manager'), :name, :name, {}, :multiple => 'true', :class => 'role_pm' %>
```

Looks like I have passed both multiple and class attributes as seperate arrays which was really not needed in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

.**You need to initialize Multiselect using the js**.

here comes my working code:-

```
###HTML FILE
##my controller has @event_types to autopopulate the values as well for edit action
<label for="events" class="control-label form-group col-md-12">Event Type: </label>   
  <div class="form_group col-md-12">
     <div class="btn-group">
          <%= select_tag("event_types", options_for_select(@event_types.pluck(:name),:multiple=>true,:required=>true) %>

      </div>       
  </div>  


###js FILE-initialise using id/class for multiselect
        $('#event_types').multiselect({
            enableFiltering: true,
            filterBehavior: 'text',
            enableCaseInsensitiveFiltering: true,
            nonSelectedText: 'Select the type of events'
        });
```

you can use `selected` attribute in select tag to select those values during edit action.Just pass it from controller..example

```
:selected => @event_types.new_record? ? nil : @event_types.pluck(:name)
```

rewriting your query...

```
<%= select_tag("event_types", options_for_select(@event_types.pluck(:name),:multiple=>true,:required=>true) %>
```

changes to :Showing names in select dropdown list

```
<%= select_tag("role_pm", options_for_select(User.where(:user_role => 'Project Manager').pluck(:name).uniq,:multiple=>true,:required=>true) %>
```

Comment: I have done that already but still it gives me an radio box to select single value but i need  checkboxes instead so that i can select multiple values

Comment: Could you rewite this query for me that can be used in your select_tag

Comment: <%= f.collection_select :role_tl, User.where(:user_role => 'Team Lead'), :name, :name, {}, {:multiple => 'true'} %>

Comment: I need to return the users name whereas the current query returns list of user object ID's

Comment: The names appear but still I dont get a checkbox in my view to select mutilple users. Instead I get radio button which allows me to select only an single value.

Comment: I have uploaded an pic that shows how my multiselect is currently being rendered  http://pasteboard.co/Z4Luq2g.png

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/112118/discussion-between-milind-and-ahkshaey-ravi).

Comment: http://davidstutz.github.io/bootstrap-multiselect/#configuration-options ....referring from library..if we use multiple...then we get checkboxes else its only radio buttons..kindly inspect using console. @AhkshaeyRavi

Comment: Actually in my html the multiple attribute is not getting set. I think thats what is causing all the agony for me

Comment: try switching the place of multiple attribute else use pure html instead of erb

Comment: can you help me with the pure html code for doing so

Comment: How do I make the selected values appear in my edit action form. Right now it does not do that?